# OpenCV setMouseCallback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am trying to set a mouseCallback function using openCV within an ros application.

So i defined a function prototype within my class defintion object_tracker looking like this:

```
class object_tracker
{    
public:
    ...
private:
    void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param );
```

Function itself looks like this:

```
void object_tracker::onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
{
...
}
```

When i now set the mouseCallback

```
setMouseCallback( "CamShift Demo", object_tracker::onMouse, 0 );
```

it says:

> /home/namco/ros/ object_tracker/src/object_tracker.cpp:323: Fehler:argument of type ‘void ( object_tracker::)(int, int, int, int, void*)’ does not match ‘cv::MouseCallback {aka void ( *)(int, int, int, int, void*)}’

But when i use this with normal cpp, everything works fine. What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56730/opencv-setmousecallback/) by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kanzhi Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3892/kanzhi-wu/) on 2014-04-06**:
Hi boFFeL,

did you solve this problem?
I met the same issue as you...

Best regards
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV's setMouseCallback does not support calling into non-static class member functions (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#cv.SetMouseCallback).

A work around for this could be declaring a static method that calls into the non-static method:

Declaration:

```
class object_tracker
{    
public:
    ...
private:
    static void onMouseStatic( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* that );
    void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags );
```

Definition:

```
void object_tracker::onMouseStatic( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* that )
{
    that->onMouse( event,  x, y, flags );
}

void object_tracker::onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags )
{
...
}
```

And add this rather than 0 if you want to the callback:

```
setMouseCallback( "CamShift Demo", object_tracker::onMouseStatic, this );
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-05-23**:
I now got: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
that->onMouse( event,  x, y, flags );

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2019-06-27**:
In theory, this should not work. When using a void pointer, you can't just dereference. You first need to type-cast it. At least, that is how I know it works. The other answer is actually type-casting it, that is why it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a quite similar solution that worked for me:

in the main.cpp file:

```
 void BallTrackingNode::mouseHandleStatic(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
 {
     BallTrackingNode* thiz = static_cast<BallTrackingNode*>(param);
     thiz->onMouse(event, x, y, flags);
 }


void BallTrackingNode::onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags)
{
    if (rect_done_)
      return;
    switch (event)
    {
    case cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
      region_rect_.width = x - region_rect_.x;
      region_rect_.height = y - region_rect_.y;
    }
    break;
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
      region_rect_ = cv::Rect(x, y, 0, 0);
      draw_box_ = true;
    }
    break;
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    {
      draw_box_ = false;
      if (region_rect_.width < 0)
      {
        region_rect_.x += region_rect_.width;
        region_rect_.width *= -1;
      }
      if (region_rect_.height < 0)
      {
        region_rect_.y += region_rect_.height;
        region_rect_.height *= -1;
      }
      rect_done_ = true;
    }
    }
}
```

call it with

```
cv::setMouseCallback(select_cloud_area_window_name_, BallTrackingNode::mouseHandleStatic, (void*)this);
```

in the header:

```
public:
  static void mouseHandleStatic( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* that );
  void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags);
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2019-06-27**:
Works beautifully.